# Hello I use laravel & Vue js i author project it working fine but this error?

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router, laravel-7

```
  Module parse failed: Unexpected token (1:0)
  You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See :// webpack . js .org/concepts#loaders
  > <template>
  |     <div class="container">
  |         <div class="row justify-content-center">
   @ ./resources/js/Router.js 4:0-53 11:15-19
   @ ./resources/js/app.js
   @ multi ./resources/js/App.js ./resources/sass/app.scss
```

in APP
require('./bootstrap');

```
window.Vue = require('vue');
import VueRouter from 'vue-router'
Vue.use(VueRouter)

import router from './Router'
 new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    router
});
```

in Router js

i importing the vue-router and vue

> import Vue from 'vue'
> import VueRouter from 'vue-router'
> Vue.use(VueRouter)
>
> ```
> import User from './components/ExampleComponent.Vue'
>
> Vue.use(VueRouter);
>
> const router = new VueRouter({
>     mode:'history',
>     routes:[
>
>         { path:'/user', component: User, } ,
>         { path:'/categories', component: categories, } ,
>     ]
> })
> ```

Comment: You instantiated the Vue import on the window object. and then you are assigning the router to Vue. have you tried window.Vue.use()? I am not sure if that is the issue though.

Comment: @JustinDuncan yes it importing in app.js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ran into this error too. In my own case, I ran into this error because I wanted to use tailwind v2.0.

I think it have something to do with Laravel Mix v6.0 or POSTCSS 8. Because Vue SFCs doesn't work with PostCSS 8-only plugins yet. Taken from (https://github.com/JeffreyWay/laravel-mix/issues/2625).

So in my own case, the steps I took are listed below.

1. I uninstall the concerned packages `npm uninstall tailwindcss postcss autoprefixer`
2. Then I installed them back with compatibility build `npm install tailwindcss@npm:@tailwindcss/postcss7-compat postcss@^7 autoprefixer@^9`

Check https://tailwindcss.com/docs/installation#post-css-7-compatibility-build

3. I added `"laravel-mix": "^5.0.1"` to the package.json file to downgrade the laravel mix from v6.0 to v5.0.1.
4. Then `npm install`
5. Finally, `npm run watch`